# Output.json displays app version code as version name

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-build

When running `assembleProdRelease` to generate APK and output files I got something weird that I couldn't explain (My app has a `prod` flavour and `release` build type).

The `output.json` file actually shows version code as version name, see below

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "artifactType": {
    "type": "APK",
    "kind": "Directory"
  },
  "applicationId": "com.example.myapp",
  "variantName": "prodDebug",
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "SINGLE",
      "filters": [],
      "properties": [],
      "versionCode": 2,
      "versionName": "2",
      "enabled": true,
      "outputFile": "app-prod-debug.apk"
    }
  ]
}
```

My build gradle (it's in Kotlin kts) is pretty standard:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionName = "1.0.0"
        versionCode = 2
    }
```

I would expect `"versionName": "1.0.0"` instead of "2" as shown in the `output.json` file.

My CI setup relies on the output file content to grab the app version from there so this basically causes me generating wrong file name.

I was wondering if anyone has come across a similar issue and how did you resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Not yet. It wasn't a big deal in my scenario so I decided to come back to it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with android gradle plugin 4.0.0. Update gradle plugin version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2' // currently 4.1.0 might also apply
```

Current version can be checked [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: Confirmed. I upgraded gradle plugin together with gradle version the other day and it was resolved. Thanks